# How to rewrite lines in a file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, replace

I am extremely new to coding and barely have any idea what I'm doing when it comes to file i/o. I was wondering if there was a way that I could overwrite a line in a text file I've opened.

Specifically, I'm making an extremely basic text game. The point is not the game though, it's for me to get used to file i/o. In essence I am trying to keep track of the total number of correct and incorrect guesses a player has made. In order to do this, I created a file where the first line would hold a number with their correct guesses, and the second line would hold a number with their incorrect guesses. I need to be able to rewrite these lines, however, in order to update them every game.

Essentially I am just wondering if there is anything similar to .readline() or anything I can do with .readline() in order to replace the first and second line of a text file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Please try to keep in mind, I am an absolute beginner, therefore the simpler the strategy, the better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read all data from file at the beginning and write all data when you need it.
Especially at the end of game. It is easer.

You can use JSON format because it is easy to convert from text file into python dictionary

```
import json

data = {
  'correct': 7,
  'incorrect': 8
}

# write data

f = open('config.txt', 'w')
json.dump(data, f)
f.close()

data['correct'] = 100
print data['correct']  # 100

# read data

f = open('config.txt', 'r')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()

print data['correct']  # 7
```